# How to trigger a repaint after isVisible property changes

Tags: c#, maui

I am trying to just make visible a button once some code is executed.
the XAML code is the following

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Pages"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Test.Model"
             x:Class="Test.Pages.LoginPage"
             Title="Login">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                <ImageButton  Clicked="OpenLogIn_Clicked" Source="login.png" />
                <Button Text="Log out" Clicked="OpenLogOut_Clicked" x:Name="logout" IsEnabled="False" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"/>
```

The property is bound with the following model:

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isVisible;

    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return isVisible; }
        set
        {
            isVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsVisible));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The model is instantiated in the constructor of the page

```cs
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
```

Later in the code of one function of the class LoginPage, I change the isVisible property, but nothing changes, not even call

```cs
private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(object sender, AuthorizationCodeResponse response)
{
    // ......some code.......
    logout.IsVisible = true;
    base.OnAppearing();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You should be setting the VM property, not directly modifying the view.  And there is no reason to call OnAppearing

Comment: `logout.IsVisible = true;` destroys the Binding that you setup in the XAML. If you want to honor that Binding, you should update the VM instead. In fact, a better practice would be for your VM to implement a command for your Button instead of handling it in your LoginPage code behind.

Comment: I would suggest CommunityToolkit.MVVM, It is one line annotation to add commands and observables,  and you won't have to use those "on_click" events or write anything by hand. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/

Comment: thanks a lot! you were absolutely right. I was updating the wrong object.once I updated the VM it worked.

Comment: @H.A.H. I will take a look into that too. everything that makes things easier deserves to be explored. ;) thanks once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.

I removed the onappearing call and I update the IsVisible property of the VM instead of the xaml object. after these two changes it worked as expected.